# Chainlink Functions: Arguments into requestConfig and Output to Custom JS

Tags: chainlink

My hackathon project involves a use case in which I'm taking user input and sending to an intermediary server for processing, and then forwarding input to the `Functions-request-config` file as a string input to the `args` field in the `requestConfig` object. I've seen in the config template notes (as well as the workshops) that `args` only takes strings as array values, so I made sure any custom arguments into `args` were of type `string`. This was done by making an async read call from a test db in the project directory.

However, when I go to validate that the value passed from `args` to my custom JS successfully made it over, I get an `undefined` object of type `string` being received. This is unexpected, especially since my code still runs, just without the proper user input being passed to my subsequent HTTPRequest.

I'm not quite sure where to begin troubleshooting this behaviour, as when I pass `args` in the config file a hard-coded string input, the `args` value is successfully copied over to my custom JS, and the HTTPRequest call executes with the correct input.

Aside from my above issue with the variable input to `args`, is it advisable to wrap the creation of the requestConfig object in a promise resolution block, since I'm awaiting a read from a db? I'm wondering if it's my inclusion of promises and callbacks in the config file that's causing the custom JS to not receive the value properly?

`Functions-request-config.js`

```
const fs = require("fs")
const db = require("./db")

// Loads environment variables from .env.enc file (if it exists)
require("@chainlink/env-enc").config()

const Location = {
  Inline: 0,
  Remote: 1,
}

const CodeLanguage = {
  JavaScript: 0,
}

const ReturnType = {
  uint: "uint256",
  uint256: "uint256",
  int: "int256",
  int256: "int256",
  string: "string",
  bytes: "Buffer",
  Buffer: "Buffer",
}

let prompt

db.getPrompt()
  .then((row) => {
    prompt = row.prompt
    console.log("Prompt from the db is: " + prompt)
    console.log("prompt type is: " + typeof prompt)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })

// Configure the request by setting the fields below
const requestConfig = {
  // Location of source code (only Inline is currently supported)
  codeLocation: Location.Inline,
  // Code language (only JavaScript is currently supported)
  codeLanguage: CodeLanguage.JavaScript,
  // String containing the source code to be executed
  source: fs.readFileSync("./Functions-request-source.js").toString(),
  //source: fs.readFileSync('./API-request-example.js').toString(),
  // Secrets can be accessed within the source code with `secrets.varName` (ie: secrets.apiKey). The secrets object can only contain string values.
  secrets: { openaiKey: process.env.OPENAI_KEY ?? "" },
  // Per-node secrets objects assigned to each DON member. When using per-node secrets, nodes can only use secrets which they have been assigned.
  perNodeSecrets: [],
  // ETH wallet key used to sign secrets so they cannot be accessed by a 3rd party
  walletPrivateKey: process.env["PRIVATE_KEY"],
  // Args (string only array) can be accessed within the source code with `args[index]` (ie: args[0]).
  args: [`${prompt}`],
  // Expected type of the returned value
  expectedReturnType: ReturnType.string,
  // Redundant URLs which point to encrypted off-chain secrets
  secretsURLs: [],
}

module.exports = requestConfig
```

Below is a screenshot of my code output. I see that I'm correctly getting my user prompt from the db, and it's of type string in the config file, but when I console log the args from the custom JS side, the prompt is no longer a string "invent me a new sandwich...." and is now undefined.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[Code execution output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVavh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your prompt variable will be undefined when the request object gets assigned to `requestConfig` because prompt gets given a value asynchronously.

The tooling reads your request config statically.  What you need to do is to find the bit in the tasks where the request config is read and just before i gets passed to the ConsumerContract's executeRequest function.   Intercept the requestObject there and (by using async await first to get the value of `prompt` set) set the value of args once the `prompt` value has been set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did find another alternative that fixes my issue going through local storage instead! Thanks for your help!